# loop through multidimensional UL to generate javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

In short I want to convert a UL list to a javascript/jquery array. My issue is that the UL can be of any length and depth of nesting.

here is a sample UL:

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>HOME</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>Page 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Page 2</span></li>
        <li>
          <span>Page 3</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Page a</span></li>
            <li><span>Page b</span></li>
            <li><span>Page c</span></li>
            <li>
              <span>Page X</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span>Page d</span></li>
                <li><span>Page e</span></li>
                <li><span>Page f</span></li>
                <li><span>Page g</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Page 4</span></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I have a basic each loop in jquery that only goes through the first nested. I need it to keep going through any li that has children and the array generated to match the nesting format:

```
var arr = [];
    $("#main > ul > li").each(function() {
        var elem = {
            brand: $(this).find(">span:first").text(),
            children: []
        };
        $(this).find(">ul>li").each(function() {
             elem.children.push($(this).find('span:first').text());
        });
        arr.push(elem);
    });
console.log(arr);
```

Here is what it outputs:

[image]
Any help would be gratefully received. I get the feeling I just need some sort of function that keeps on looping down a li's until it comes back false to having any child ul/li.

Comment: Please add the expected output for your markup.

Comment: This is  my problem the UL size and nesting depth can be anything. The output array needs dynamic to match the nesting format of the UL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is through recursion:

```js
var list = [];
$("#main > ul > li").each(function() {
    list.push(buildObject($(this)));
});

function buildObject(parent){
  var obj = {
    brand: parent.find(">span:first").text(),
    children: [],
  }
  parent.find(">ul>li").each(function() {
     obj.children.push(buildObject($(this)));
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>HOME</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>Page 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Page 2</span></li>
        <li>
          <span>Page 3</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Page a</span></li>
            <li><span>Page b</span></li>
            <li><span>Page c</span></li>
            <li>
              <span>Page X</span>
              <ul>
                <li><span>Page d</span></li>
                <li><span>Page e</span></li>
                <li><span>Page f</span></li>
                <li><span>Page g</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Page 4</span></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to think of! works like a charm! Thanks you!